# table caption is in lowercase

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I have an issue regarding the table caption. I'm writing an `IEEEtran` journal manuscript. I have a table in my article, but the caption doesn't appear in uppercase as expected. I used to remove the caption package from the preamble, it appeared that the problem is solved, however the figures captions are affected.

here is my script preamble

```
\documentclass[journal,10pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot]{IEEEtran}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
```

My table is defined as

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Different values of $\protect\gamma ^{\ast }$.}
\label{tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cccccccc}
\hline
\backslashbox{$C$}{$\overline{\gamma }_{1} [dB]$} & $0$ & $5$ & $10$ & $15$
& $20$ & $25$ & $30$ & $35$ \\ \hline
$C=0.25$ & $0.1558$ & $0.3214$ & $0.5385$ & $0.7408$ & $0.8771$ & $0.9483$ &
$0.9798$ & $0.9925$ \\ \hline
$C=0.5$ & $0.1486$ & $0.3122$ & $0.5307$ & $0.7364$ & $0.8752$ & $0.9476$ & $%
0.9796$ & $0.9924$ \\ \hline
$C=0.8$ & $0.1430$ & $0.3038$ & $0.5228$ & $0.7317$ & $0.8732$ & $0.9469$ & $%
0.9793$ & $0.9923$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
```

Please help me to figure out the solution to this issue.

Comment: Please do not post such fragments only. The `caption` package and `IEEEtran` class are not compatible anyway

Comment: Don't worry about the layout, you are providing the content, IEEE takes care of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian Hupfer has already pointed out in a comment, the `caption` package isn't compatible with the `IEEEtran` document class; you should have been getting a warning message to this effect.

Since virtually all of the table is in math mode, you can save yourself from having to type a lot of `$` symbols by switching from a `tabular` environment to an `array` environment.

Don't use the obsolete `slashbox` package, which isn't distributed anymore with TeXLive. Instead, use the `diagbox` package.

Finally, do consider giving your table a far more "open" look. An example is provide in the second table in the following screenshot and code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,10pt,onecolumn,draftclsnofoot]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % not needed
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
%%\usepackage{caption} % doesn't work with "IEEEtran" class
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%%\usepackage{slashbox} % obsolete -- use "diagbox" package instead
\usepackage{diagbox}
%%%\usepackage{mathrsfs} % don't load any package twice
\usepackage{xcolor} % more modern than "color"
\usepackage{booktabs} % <--- new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Different values of $\gamma^{\ast}$.}
\label{tab1}
\centering
$\begin{array}{l|cccccccc@{}}
\hline
$\backslashbox{$C$}{$\bar{\gamma}_1$ [dB]}$
     & 0 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 \\ 
\hline
0.25 & 0.1558 & 0.3214 & 0.5385 & 0.7408 & 0.8771 & 0.9483 & 0.9798 & 0.9925 \\ 
\hline
0.5  & 0.1486 & 0.3122 & 0.5307 & 0.7364 & 0.8752 & 0.9476 & 0.9796 & 0.9924 \\ 
\hline
0.8  & 0.1430 & 0.3038 & 0.5228 & 0.7317 & 0.8732 & 0.9469 & 0.9793 & 0.9923 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Same table, but with a more ``open'' look}
\label{tab1}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} l *{8}{c} @{}}
\toprule
C & \multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{\bar{\gamma}_1 \text{ [dB]}}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-9}
     & 0 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 \\ 
\midrule
0.25 & 0.1558 & 0.3214 & 0.5385 & 0.7408 & 0.8771 & 0.9483 & 0.9798 & 0.9925 \\ 
0.5  & 0.1486 & 0.3122 & 0.5307 & 0.7364 & 0.8752 & 0.9476 & 0.9796 & 0.9924 \\ 
0.8  & 0.1430 & 0.3038 & 0.5228 & 0.7317 & 0.8732 & 0.9469 & 0.9793 & 0.9923 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```